# Display javascript alert as toast

Tags: javascript, java, android, events

I'm sure this has been asked before but the solutions i found can't work in my case...

(One thing to know: I'm a complete beginner with java/android)

as the title says I'm trying to display a javascript alert as a toast but all the solutions i found use the `WebChromeClient` and the `OnJsAlert` problem is, im using `WebViewClient` and i have overridden a lot of it's stuff... some stuff that the chrome one doesn't support... So, my question is: Is it somehow possible to get the javascript alerts from a page so i can handle them with the normal `WebViewClient`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample code that will work in your html page

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
   function clickFunction() {
        M.toast({html: 'I am a toast!'});
   }
</script>
<body>
 <a onclick="clickFunction()" class="btn">Toast!</a>
</body>
```

Reference: https://materializecss.com/toasts.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! problem is: i can't edit the page's javascript and/or html

Comment: It depends on what you are using, are you using android studio or html or something else? note that java and javascript are completely different languages

Comment: i know I'm currently making game thingy i made the whole thing in js/html but the code is now uploaded to a server that hosts it, and i cant edit it right now.. I'm using android studio to try and convert it into an app. I just started learning java and how android development works... as far as i understood webviewclient and webchromeclient are two different things and only webchromeclient has a thing that can execute code whenever the site sends an alert. but I'm using webviewclient and i have overridden a lot of its stuff hence i don't want to change it to a webchrome client,

Comment: That's a bit hacky, depends on how the javascript is structured on the client side some structure like local variables can't be overriden; what you could do is load the html file first, save it in a file, edit the file, then load it in your webView

Comment: haha seems like too much work for a simple alert haha... isn't there anything i could do that can just capture an alert something like webchromview's OnJsAlert()?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this light and simple [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library which is only **1KB** in size.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```

### Check [documentation](https://toastmaker.wirehall.com/) for more examples.